# Run publish website folder on Local IIS 7, 8

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2013

In visual studio 2013, publish the website  using one click publish button. Publish method used is file system.

[image]

I want to run the publish folder website to Local IIS7 Or IIS8. But after adding the application to Local IIS it gives error on browser.

> 'HTTP 404 The webpage cannot be found'

Comment: Validate .net version in app pool. Also try running aspnet_regiis -i

Comment: Is it working now ? Did u try running your project using your ip address ?

Comment: Yes it is working now. I have deselected the IIS windows features which are on previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run publish folder on local IIS allows some features along with .Net framework from Windows features which are as follows:

[image]

and place publish folder in following location:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Default Web Sites